# Intercept data to specific port or change port of sftp

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, openbsd

My program is running on a machine and I need to intercept data, which is transferred via sftp protocol to this machine.

Currently I have two options how do this:

1. Try use the PCAP librart - [pcap4j](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j)
   *I would not like to use third-party libraries*
2. Change the configuration of the sftp:
   sftp will be listen othe port, e.g. 9999 and my program will work instead sftp, i.e I will receive all packages, which come to port 22, process it and forward it to sftp (port 9999).
   *This solution fits for me, but I assume that it is more complex.*

What is the best choice?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Omg! Just now I understand what option 2 is very complex, because all data is encrypted.

Comment: If you want to duplicate the data take a look at `dup-to` in `pf.conf`. If you want to redirect it to a different port try `rdr-to`. `man pf.conf` is your friend.